# What does "code" mean in this context?

Tags: c, keyword

I was looking at some sample code for an MCU I am working with and saw the following declaration:

```
// A full cycle, 16-bit, 2's complement sine wave lookup table
int code SINE_TABLE[256] = {

   0x0000, 0x0324, 0x0647, 0x096a, 0x0c8b, 0x0fab, 0x12c8, 0x15e2,
   0x18f8, 0x1c0b, 0x1f19, 0x2223, 0x2528, 0x2826, 0x2b1f, 0x2e11,
   0x30fb, 0x33de, 0x36ba, 0x398c, 0x3c56, 0x3f17, 0x41ce, 0x447a,
   0x471c, 0x49b4, 0x4c3f, 0x4ebf, 0x5133, 0x539b, 0x55f5, 0x5842,
   0x5a82, 0x5cb4, 0x5ed7, 0x60ec, 0x62f2, 0x64e8, 0x66cf, 0x68a6,
   0x6a6d, 0x6c24, 0x6dca, 0x6f5f, 0x70e2, 0x7255, 0x73b5, 0x7504,
   0x7641, 0x776c, 0x7884, 0x798a, 0x7a7d, 0x7b5d, 0x7c29, 0x7ce3,
   0x7d8a, 0x7e1d, 0x7e9d, 0x7f09, 0x7f62, 0x7fa7, 0x7fd8, 0x7ff6,
   0x7fff, 0x7ff6, 0x7fd8, 0x7fa7, 0x7f62, 0x7f09, 0x7e9d, 0x7e1d,
   0x7d8a, 0x7ce3, 0x7c29, 0x7b5d, 0x7a7d, 0x798a, 0x7884, 0x776c,
   0x7641, 0x7504, 0x73b5, 0x7255, 0x70e2, 0x6f5f, 0x6dca, 0x6c24,
   0x6a6d, 0x68a6, 0x66cf, 0x64e8, 0x62f2, 0x60ec, 0x5ed7, 0x5cb4,
   0x5a82, 0x5842, 0x55f5, 0x539b, 0x5133, 0x4ebf, 0x4c3f, 0x49b4,
   0x471c, 0x447a, 0x41ce, 0x3f17, 0x3c56, 0x398c, 0x36ba, 0x33de,
   0x30fb, 0x2e11, 0x2b1f, 0x2826, 0x2528, 0x2223, 0x1f19, 0x1c0b,
   0x18f8, 0x15e2, 0x12c8, 0x0fab, 0x0c8b, 0x096a, 0x0647, 0x0324,
   0x0000, 0xfcdc, 0xf9b9, 0xf696, 0xf375, 0xf055, 0xed38, 0xea1e,
   0xe708, 0xe3f5, 0xe0e7, 0xdddd, 0xdad8, 0xd7da, 0xd4e1, 0xd1ef,
   0xcf05, 0xcc22, 0xc946, 0xc674, 0xc3aa, 0xc0e9, 0xbe32, 0xbb86,
   0xb8e4, 0xb64c, 0xb3c1, 0xb141, 0xaecd, 0xac65, 0xaa0b, 0xa7be,
   0xa57e, 0xa34c, 0xa129, 0x9f14, 0x9d0e, 0x9b18, 0x9931, 0x975a,
   0x9593, 0x93dc, 0x9236, 0x90a1, 0x8f1e, 0x8dab, 0x8c4b, 0x8afc,
   0x89bf, 0x8894, 0x877c, 0x8676, 0x8583, 0x84a3, 0x83d7, 0x831d,
   0x8276, 0x81e3, 0x8163, 0x80f7, 0x809e, 0x8059, 0x8028, 0x800a,
   0x8000, 0x800a, 0x8028, 0x8059, 0x809e, 0x80f7, 0x8163, 0x81e3,
   0x8276, 0x831d, 0x83d7, 0x84a3, 0x8583, 0x8676, 0x877c, 0x8894,
   0x89bf, 0x8afc, 0x8c4b, 0x8dab, 0x8f1e, 0x90a1, 0x9236, 0x93dc,
   0x9593, 0x975a, 0x9931, 0x9b18, 0x9d0e, 0x9f14, 0xa129, 0xa34c,
   0xa57e, 0xa7be, 0xaa0b, 0xac65, 0xaecd, 0xb141, 0xb3c1, 0xb64c,
   0xb8e4, 0xbb86, 0xbe32, 0xc0e9, 0xc3aa, 0xc674, 0xc946, 0xcc22,
   0xcf05, 0xd1ef, 0xd4e1, 0xd7da, 0xdad8, 0xdddd, 0xe0e7, 0xe3f5,
   0xe708, 0xea1e, 0xed38, 0xf055, 0xf375, 0xf696, 0xf9b9, 0xfcdc,
};
```

I have never see "code" used as a keyword like this. I tried searching but given the word "code" fits in virtually any question I couldn't find the answer. What does it mean?

Comment: Please search the rest of the code with `grep` or similar tools to find where is the definition of `code`, it seems to be a macro.

Comment: Which MCU? Also: It could be a macro. Run it through `cpp` and see if it's replaced with something more obvious, like an `__attribute__`. (My immediate suspicion is that it tells the compiler to place the array in progmem.)

Comment: @Wintermute The MCU in question is a C8051F370. I have never seen such macro's so I didn't consider it but my experience with C only extends over about the past week.

Comment: @Fr33dan Using the C51 tools from Keil?

Comment: @Wintermute I think those are the ones, it's from Keil but I don't remember the name of the toolset.

Comment: @Fr33dan See http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_memtypes.htm , particularly http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_code.htm

Comment: You need to declare SINE_TABLE as a `const` no matter what that non-standard keyword does. This is especially important for embedded systems! You _do not_ want this table to end up in RAM, you want it to be in flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code` is not a C keyword. It's probably some kind of macro that the developers of the program you're looking at invented.

You will have to search your source code file and its `#includes` for a `#define` that defines what `code` stands for.

Since that's a rather common task, here's my `grep` magic

```
grep -Rei '#define.*code' .
```

should find all lines that contain such a definition in your current folder.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a standard keyword.

It's either an extension by the specific compiler that code was written for, or a macro.

It's probably used to instruct the linker to put the data in "code space", which is common when there's little RAM.

I would expect a sane linker setup to do that if the data was `const`, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: Some MCUs use different instructions to read from progmem than RAM (AVR, for example), so placing data in progmem can break code that attempts to read through a pointer. On such architectures, you have to request the placement explicitly. By contrast, on bare-metal ARM it is usual to solve the problem with a linker script and shove all const data into ROM (because ARM doesn't have special instructions to read from ROM).

Comment: The data needs to be `const` regardless. Typically, MCU compilers do indeed put tables in flash upon encountering `const`. To generate proper instructions for fetching that data, that's another thing, which may be needed in addition to `const`. More commonly you'd use the non-standard `far` keyword to generate  for example banked memory access instructions, on 8/16 bit MCUs with more than 65k of mapped memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's an extension specific to your compiler.

You have to read your compiler [documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_memtypes.htm):

It's a memory type specifier (`code`, `xdata`, `bdata`, etc.) that you need to include when you declare variables. `code` indicates that the object is stored in the program memory.

Comment: Btw, I didn't notice @Wintermute just put the same link in the question comments.